# How to share files/folders in Sun VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running on Windows 7 and using Sun's [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), and I already shared my folders in the settings of my VirtualBox installation. The problem is I can't figure-out how I can access it. I also tried googling it, but I think I'm not doing it right.

Comment: What OS are you running the virtual machine with?  Is Windows 7 the host or the guest OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Guest Additions and setup a shared folder (if you haven't done this yet), then use the following command from a command prompt:

```
net use x: \\vboxsvr\shared
```

X: is the drive letter that will be assigned to the network drive

Replace *shared* with the folder name you provided when setting up the shared folder.

You should get this:

[image]

If you don't want to map the shared folder, you can always type `\\vboxsvr\shared` into the address bar of Windows Explorer or the Run box.

Comment: It worked like charm! Thanks man! I haven't installed Guest Additions that's why I can't access.

Comment: you're more than welcome.