# How to access the share folder in VM?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share files/folders in Sun VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/79347/how-to-share-files-folders-in-sun-virtualbox)

I create a VM machine with virtualbox, and the network type must be NAT.
after that i type \10.0.2.15 in my host machine, I can not access to the share folder, How can I achieve this ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not that simple using NAT.

In my opinion the best solution for your situation is to set up an ftp server on the guest and access it via windows explorer or any ftp client from the host. To do that you will need to set up NAT port forwarding for the desired ftp port: 
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward