# How do I transfer files to my Windows 8 VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share files/folders in Sun VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/79347/how-to-share-files-folders-in-sun-virtualbox)

I have Windows 8 Enterprise edition running in an Oracle VirtualBox. There's a file on my (real) PC desktop that I want to move to my VirtualBox. How do I do that?

Comment: Generally, install the Guest Additions and then create a shared folders. I don't know if VirtualBox supports drag and drop already but in any case that would be available after Guest Additions are installed. See here for some info: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Comment: Why do you put that in a comment, and not an answer?

Comment: Because I don't have VirtualBox here and can't test it. I know that works with Windows 7 but haven't tried it yet with Windows 8. I wouldn't like to give an untested answer to a question, for example there could be an issue with the current version of the additions and Windows 8 (and this question is tagged Windows 8, so not Windows generic).

Comment: Makes sense, Xandy.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the VirtualBox Guest extensions first. Download and then click on to install to host system. Then install the exteension in the virtual system by loading it thru the CD.
Once you have guest extensions, it's just a two step drag-and-drop. (one on each side).